# Wordpress Custom Search Filter

Tags: wordpress, search

I've can't seem to find a solution to this so I'm posting here.

Basically I'm trying to build a basic filter for property listings. All the property listings are just posts with custom fields. For example, one of the properties has these values in the custom fields:

```
custom field   value
------------   -----
area           150
rooms          4
bathrooms      2
garage         1
alfresco       1
study          1
theatre        1
```

My search form HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="get" id="advanced_search" action="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>/" >
        <fieldset>

           <label>Rooms 
           <select name="rooms">
                <option value="">Any</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
           </select>
           </label>

           <label>Bathrooms
                <select name="bathrooms">
                    <option value="">Any</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
           </label>

           <label>Garage
                <select name="garage">
                    <option value="">Any</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
           </label>

           <label>Area (square metres)
                <select name="garage">
                    <option value="">Any</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                    <option value="150">150</option>
                    <option value="200">200</option>
                    <option value="250">250</option>
                </select>
           </label>

           <label><input type="checkbox" name="theatre" value="1" /><span>Home Theatre</span></label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" name="study" value="1" /><span>Study</span></label>
           <label><input type="checkbox" name="alfresco" value="1" /><span>Alfresco</span></label>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

What I am wanting to do is let the user use this filter to only show posts on a search results page that match it.

There's a slight catch too: all these custom field represents a minimum value. So if they selected "200" from "Area", "1" from "Alfresco", then it needs to show all properties that are 200 and higher and have at least 1 Alfresco area.

And - I'd like to limit the search filter to just the category called "properties".

Not asking much? :-P

Any help would be appreciated.